# How to redirect logs from fluentd (log collector) to GCP Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, fluent-docker

**I want my fluentd ( log Collector)  to forward logs to GCP Cloud storage.**
Currently, docker container logs are collected by fluentd and forwarded to loki.

What steps to be followed to redirect logs from fluentd to Cloud Storage.
After creating bucket in GCP Cloud Storage. What changes need to be done in fluentd.conf

Looking for an Documentation or any help in configuring GCP Cloud Storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add @type google_cloud under  config to send logs to Google Cloud's operations suite (formerly Stackdriver)

Comment: Sure I will take the tour and post the answer as per guidelines

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33535178)